# Close JQuery Image with click outside div

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I would like to be able to close hide displayed pop up gallery 3 ways: clicking on image as I already have. Close when I click outside box and close when another menu link is selected i.e. click home and popup reset closes.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Website</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style-projects-jquery.css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascrip" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localscroll-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x';
            $.localScroll();
        });
        </script>  

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#gallery a").lightBox();
    });
    </script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".gallery").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

 </script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".menu a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

 </script>  

</head>
<body>

                <a name="home"></a>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box1">Box 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box2">Box 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box3">Box 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box4">Box 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box5">Box 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box6">Box 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box7">Box 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#box8">Box 8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="box6" class="box">
            <h2><a name="box6">Sixth Box</a></h2>
            <p><div id="gallery">

        <li>
            <a href="photos/image1.jpg" title="Image 1 $('#gallery').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image2.jpg" title="Image 2 $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image3.jpg" title="Image 3 $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image3.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image4.jpg" title="Image 4 $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image4.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image5.jpg" title="Image 5 $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image5.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>

</div></p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
     var elem = $(e.target).attr('class');
     if (elem != 'slidingDiv') {  ////slidingDiv is a class name where do not want to close when click on it...
         ///Your code to close popup.....
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating separate ids for each element and tag them in a hide block as below .

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ((e.target.id != "a_IDName") && (e.target.id != "imgIDName"){ 
         // if click is not in 'mydiv'
         $("#a_IDName").hide("fast");
    }
   //More if's for each Image Condition.
});
```

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the jquery selector that calls the plugin seems to be wrong. Ty changing in for `$('a#gallery').lightBox();` and adding an id 'gallery' to the links you want to expose that behavior. I checked the [site](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) and it seems that you don't need any other script to make the images hide by clicking outside.

Answer (score 0):

well you need to handle document click event for this

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
        //apply your code here to check which element is clicked by using $(e.target)
});
```

`$(e.target)` will give you object on which click event has been fired after that you can check by class or id